# Clearing textarea append()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to draw rectangles and capture the coordinates in a textarea.  A button is provided to clear the textarea.

Problem **1**: The textarea is not cleared (deleted text is still there the next time the textarea is updated).

```
$("#clearoutput").click(function (e) {
    $("#output").empty();
});
```

I tried `.val("")` but that only seems to clear the textarea form.  The text is still visible in the html source.  Plus it stays cleared, won't allow new entries.

Problem **2**: I'm not sure how append works.  If I don't put `.empty()` on mousedown (ie. start of new drawing), it will append the entire textarea instead of appending the last line.  Why is that?

For the code and instructions to reproduce problem 1 see http://jsfiddle.net/dpqm77b7/
(code is adapted from [jQuery drag and draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884803/jquery-drag-and-draw))

Thanks!

Comment: you need this?http://jsfiddle.net/dpqm77b7/3/

Comment: use $("#output").val() to set values to textarea.

Comment: @woodduck Can you check all the answers ?

Comment: had you tried $("output").html('');

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Your fiddle is the closest so far, but I wanted to keep the coordinates from the first two rectangles.  Your demo only shows 1 line in the textarea.  I'll take a closer look at your code.

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention. The clear button is not supposed to clear the drawings, only the textarea.  In my actual code I have a separate mechanism to remove the selection-box elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several bugs in your code.

1 -  You have a event listener which applied multiple times. You have to add `.off("mousemove")` and `.off("mouseup")` on your container.

2 - Input fields doesn't have DOM childs. So you can't append a DOM element in your input. You can use `.val()` instead of `.append()` for input elements.

3 - Your clear buttons works clearing textarea but not draws. So i stored draws information into an array. After clearing you can access old drawing infomations.

You can see this fiddle working perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/dpqm77b7/5/

(woodduck added 1 line (as per comment) to make it work as desired: http://jsfiddle.net/df2te8oy/)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I will read them carefully.  In the meantime, I just tried the fiddle, but i don't see a change in the behaviour.  The text created pre-clearing is still present post-clearing.

Comment: I don't want to clear the draws, just the textarea.  Do I still need the array?   In order to clear the textarea, I tried outputs=[]; in the clearoutput function (after line 8 in your fiddle) and that seems to work.  So the array idea does work.

Comment: Using array only for old draws information storing. You don't use, if you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**
the reason `.val('')` is using as you are appending the content to textarea rather that setting it. to set content empty in textboxes/textareas use

```
$("#clearoutput").click(function (e) {
  $("#output").val('');
});
```

**Problem 2:**

You should rather use `.val()` to get/set/modify textarea contents

```
$("#output").val(function(i,oldval){
  return !oldval.length ? os :oldval+ "\n" + os;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a1g4z8mv/)**

Comment: I tried that (or something along those lines) but I didn't see a difference with using append.  In your workign demo, lines are duplicated which is not what I want.